# Make particles longer without changing the amount

Tags: animation, particles

I have a particle system where I have it at a certain speed, I have it at 250, but when I bring it up to for example, 1000, the amount of particles decrease by a lot, and it doesn't look right. How do I keep the same amount of particles while trying to make the particles last much longer?

Comment: Sorry, may I ask, where are you setting the speed?

Comment: I set the speed in timestep in the physics tab. It's at it's default as .0.40 which is the speed I prefer it. But when I increase the end from 250 to 1000, the amount of the particles changes, I notice it's slower and with less particles.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're talking about... You increase the end from 250 to 1000? So, you set the end frame to 1000? And what do you do with the number of particles? Let's say you have a number of 1000 particles and set the end to 250, this means 1000/250 = 4 particles are emitted per frame. If you set the end to 1000 this means, 1000/1000 = 1 particle is emitted per frame. That has nothing to do with the timestep. The number of particles is the total amount over the range of the animation, the amount doesn't get more automatically when you set the end to a higher frame.

Comment: But how can I have the same total amount of particles emit when making the range of the animation longer? I have 200 particles emitting from my emitter, the end is 250. I set the new end to 1000, the particles that emit begin to emit less. I'm trying to have the same amount of particles emit just last much longer. https://imgur.com/a/lbxVFbH